# MATLAB on Ubuntu 17.10 installation

Tags: software-installation, matlab, 17.10

Before I start, let me say that I have browsed many, many pages for help on this topic, but can't find relative information.

I am trying to install MATLAB R2017b on Ubuntu 17.10, but I can't. I need to use the internet for my license, so I'm restricted to GUI usage. Using the command, `sudo ./install`, in the installation folder would do this in earlier iterations of MATLAB and Ubuntu, but it does not launch the installer for some reason in Ubuntu 17.10 with MATLAB R2017b. Instead, the program returns:

```
➜  matlab_R2017b_glnxa64 ./install
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
Finished
```

Using a local installation only for the user by removing the `sudo` command, the installation gets stuck at this point:

[image: Image of error thrown by MATLAB installer]

I would prefer to install it for all users if possible.

Comment: It seems that you missed file shown in error message (jxbrowser_glnxa64_1500942976.enc) or have corrupted files. Read log-file from error message. Root installation may not fail on Xorg (not Wayland).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wayland doesn't allow for running X apps as root by default. Run the following command first:

```
xhost si:localuser:root
```

Then "sudo ./install" should perform as expected.